# VBA in Excel to summarize values based on 2 conditions - 2 worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have one workbook with 2 worksheets.

Worksheet 1 contains of the following columns:

```
HScode | Description | CountryOfOrigin | Quantity |NetWeight |GrossWeight | StatsQty | Amount
```

Worksheet 2 contains of the same columns.

**Condition** : In worksheet 1, When `HSCode` and `CountryOfOrigin` are equal, then the sum of `NetWeight`, `GrossWeight`, `Quantity`, `StatsQty` and `Amount` for that particular `HSCode` and `CountryOfOrigin` should be summarized and transferred to worksheet 2.

Comment: Please post an example of code you have tried so far.

Comment: In case you don't have anything, yet, read up on `for each` loops, build one to go through sheet 1 and for each line, process `If` clause with your criteria. The `Offset` method will be helpful to address the neighboring cells. If the criteria are matched, copy the row to sheet 2. Your question is quite common and as such you should be able to find many examples on Stackoverflow and Google.

Comment: You don't need VBA codes when you can gain it by `SUMIF` and an additional column or `SUMIFS` ;).

Comment: As this sheet will be circulated to about 5-10 people I need it to be in a Macro that's why insisted on VBA.. I have not worked on VBA much so I am not aware of how to go ahead with this.. I tried the SUMIF function but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

This is not a site where you can post a specification and expect to get a macro coded to your requirements.  It can happen when the answerer is interested in the question for his/her own reasons but that is rare.  This is particularly true of your requirement which is so basic.

Search the internet for “Excel VBA tutorial”.  There are many to choose from and I would expect most will cover everything you need within the first few pages.  If this is the first of many macros then you may, like me, prefer a book.  I visited a good library; reviewed their Excel VBA Primers; borrowed those I liked the best; tried them at home then bought the one I preferred.  Twelve years later, I still look at that book occasionally.

Next you need to design your macro so you can decide which VBA statements you need in which sequence.  Consider how you would handle this manually:

```
Erase current contents of worksheet 2.
Copy header row from worksheet 1 to worksheet 2.
Set NextFreeRowForWorksheet2 = 2.
Examine each data row of worksheet 1:
    If value of HScode cell = value of CountryOfOrigin cell then
        Copy required information from current row of Worksheet 1 to 
          row NextFreeRowForWorksheet2 of Worksheet 2
        Add 1 to NextFreeRowForWorksheet2
```

The VBA statements to match that specification are all very simple and, as I said, will be near the beginning of any tutorial.

Have a go; it will not be as difficult as you think.  You can post as many little questions as you like so come back with code that does not work as you expect.  I found being able to code VBA macros a real asset and I expect you will as well.  A little effort now will repay itself over and over again.

Comment: Thanks but i found an easier option using 'Pivot Tables'. :). Also, I wasn't looking for anyone to code the macro.. Was just expecting a few answers as to how to go about the whole process as I am new to VBA!